# How to increase memory at startup?

Tags: node.js, v8

is there an option for node.js to increase initial allocated memory?
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/node-js-increase-the-memory-limit-for-your-process

the `--max-old-space-size` seems to increase max memory but what about initial memory?
Kind of like xmx and xms for the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

V8 developer here. The short answer is: no.

The reason no such option exists is that adding fresh pages to the heap is so fast that there is no significant benefit to doing it up front.

V8 does have a flag `--initial-old-space-memory`, but it **doesn't** increase the initial allocation. Instead, what it means is "don't bother doing (old-space) GC while the heap size is below this limit". If you set that to, e.g., 1000 (MB), and then allocate 800MB of unreachable objects, and then just wait, then V8 will sit around forever with 800MB of garbage on the heap and won't lift a finger to get rid of any of that.

I'm not sure in what scenario this behavior would be useful (it's not like it will turn off GC entirely; GC will just run less frequently, but fewer GCs on a bigger heap don't necessarily add up to less total time than more GCs on a smaller heap), so I would strongly recommend to **measure the effect on your particular workload carefully before using this flag -- if it *were* a good idea to have this on by default, then it *would* be on by default!**

If I had to guess: this flag *might* be beneficial if you know that (1) your application will have a large amount of "eternal" (=lives as long as the app is running) data on the heap, and (2) you can estimate the amount of that data with reasonable accuracy. E.g.: if you know that at any given time, your old-space will consist of 500MB of always-reachable-anyway data *plus* any potentially-freeable-garbage, you could use this flag to tell V8 "if old-space size is below 600MB (=500MB plus a little), then don't bother trying to find garbage, it won't be worth the effort".